# PULP results. Get value for every route of the objective function

Tags: python, pulp

I'm solving transportation problem with `pulp`.

In the end, I receive a list of routes with their varvalues and the value of the objective function (total transportation costs). But how do I get not only varvalue, but also the result of the objective function for every route? (varvalue multiplied by costs for every route)

```py
for x in prob.variables():
    if x.varValue > 0:
        print(x.name, "=", x.varValue)
```

I added `prob.objective()` to the print, but I do not receive the results